# Relative import from parent directory and run as standalone file

Tags: python

I have two files in the following tree structure

```
├── __init__.py
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── child.py
└── top.py
```

The top.py file looks like this

```
variable = "I live in the top directory"
```

The child.py looks like this

```
from ..top import variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print variable
```

If I try to run the file through `python pkg/child.py` I get an error saying: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. If run it from the `pkg` directory as `python child.py` I get the same error.

Reading from the answers provided in this answer: 
[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) I tried doing `python -m pkg.child` from the parent directory. Then I get the error: `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`.

So I'm starting to run out of ideas. How should you do it?

Comment: That will happen if you run `child.py` directly; instead, import the functionality from *outside* the package (i.e. above the directory shown in your question) and use it there.

Comment: Yes, but now the question was about how you should do it if you wanted to run child.py independently.

Comment: If you want to run `child.py` independently, you can't use intra-package imports, because now you're not in a package. Perhaps the XY problem here is: how and why have you ended up with this structure?

Comment: I found this useful during the developement stage with the test and debug code at the bottom of each module. I want to run the module files directly to test and debug the functions implemented within module. Is there a better way to do this than trying to run the module file directly?

Comment: @Boocko, rather than running the modules separately to try and debug them that way I find it rather useful to write tests for the functions in the modules and then drop a pdb statement and debug it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the directory containing `top.py` is called `foo`.
Then change your current working directory [to the *parent of `foo`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458607/190597) so that that directory will be included in `sys.path`.

```
cd /path/to/parent/of/foo
```

Then running `child.py` as a module:

```
python -m foo.pkg.child
```

yields

```
I live in the top directory
```

---

```
cd /path/to/foo
python -m  pkg.child
```

does not work because the relative import

```
from ..top import variable
```

refers to `foo`, the package which is two directories above child.py. `foo` is
not recognized as a package if you are sitting in the *directory* `foo` and run `python -m pkg.child`.

Comment: Wonderful. I tried emulating that, but apparently I missed that part. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can append a relative path to the `top` package to the search path in `child.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from top import variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print variable
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `os` module? My crack at `child.py`

```py
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
os.chdir(dir_path)

from top import variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print variable
```